# Is there any Datastructure like Map<K,V,W, ...>?

Tags: java, dictionary

Sometimes i need to store more than one value to a key in a `Map`. I know several methods to solve this problem like:

- Creating own `Map<K,V,W>` Implementation

  - hard to write, could be easily reused, problem if more Values are needed
- Use n `Map<K,V>`

  - easy to implement, takes a lot of Objects, Key is saved many many times: what happens if you delete one key somewhere?
- Use a `Map<K, Map<I, V>>` and store the values with a second key

  - easy to implement, may having problems while iterating (null values), need to take track of the value keys as well
- Create a Class that stores `K, V, W, ...` and use a `List<MyStorageClass>` (or `Map<K, MyStorageClass>`)

  - seems to be a good choice: easy to implement, but maybe need to implement many interfaces (e.g. `Compareable`)
- ... probably many more

but i wonder what is the best practise Java way (yes i know: "it depends")? Or is there even a language build in feature that i can use to have minimal implementation effort?

Comment: Could you explain how this is meant to work - I understand Map<K,V>

Comment: `MyStorageClass` is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: @DaveRlz Its just a Map like `Map<K,V>` but having more then one value like `Map<K, Value1, Value2, ..., ValueN>` so you can add multiple Datatypes and Values to a single Key.

Answer (score 7):

```
 Sometimes i need to store more than one value to a key in a Map
```

Why not use a multimap then? [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: also `Multimap` is not the sames as a `Map<K, V, W, ...`

Comment: @reox true. But MultiMap<String,MyObject>, where myObect has V,W,... parameters is. ;)

Comment: okay, but then i could also use a normal `Map<K, MyStorageClass>`

Comment: @reox true. then why wouldn't you? Why isn't such a utility class present already? Because it would be pretty hard to implement. For example values() method, what will it return? And so on

Comment: yes... this would be more like a database with one key and multiple value columns

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`MultiValueMap`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html) from Spring.

Comment: but MultiValueMap is `public interface MultiValueMap<K,V> extends Map<K,List<V>>`

so i can't store different types of values